# Mostrar imagenes de MYSQL en php

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando mostrar una imagen por cada registro guardado en la base de datos. He conseguido que por cada registro muestre un cuadrado, pero no consigo que la imagen se vea.

Tengo un archivo que es eventos.php que es este:

```
<?php
include_once('conexion.php');
$consultaimg = consultaimg();
?>
Luego esta la pagina web y en el body tengo esto de php:

<div class="row">
<?php
while ($variable = $consultaimg->fetch_assoc())
{

  ?>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="<?php print $variable; ?>"  style="width:100%">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php

}
?>
```

Si "inspecciono" mi pagina web, en la ruta donde tendría que estar la imagen me sale esto:

> Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebPBLlocal\eventos.php on line 92

En la base de datos guardo las imágenes con rutas a internet así: `https://...`

Comment: esto seria algo asi: `<?php echo $variable['imagen']; ?>`  en caso de que no hayas guardado la ruta, puede hacerlo asi: `<img src="imagen/<?php echo $variable['imagen']; ?>"  style="width:100%">`

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas hacer algo como

```
print $variable["Nombre columna"]
```

Donde `Nombre columna` contiene la url de la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu consulta SQL sea algo como `SELECT nombreImagen, rutaImagen FROM Imagenes;`, tu php debería llamar a la ruta de imagen de acuerdo con la columna que corresponda en la consulta, por ejemplo:

```
<?php while ($variable = $consultaimg->fetch_assoc()): ?>
    <img src="<?php print $variable['rutaImagen']; ?>" style="width:100%">
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

En la línea `while ($variable = $consultaimg->fetch_assoc())` se está asignando un array asociativo a una variable, y por eso se genera el mensaje de advertencia 'Array to string conversion'.

La solución por tanto estaría en cambiar esa línea por `foreach ($variable as $consultaimg->fetch_assoc())`.

Answer (score 0):

En este línea:

```
<img src="<?php print $variable; ?>"  style="width:100%">
```

deberías de cambiarla por

```
<img src="<?php print [$variable]; ?>"  style="width:100%">
```

Esto si tienes bien la DB debería de traerte la ULR de la imagen o el nombre de tu imagen, si trae el nombre de tu imagen, deberás concatenar la ruta